# How to change grid floor?

Tags: animation

Is it possible to change the grid floor?

It is hard to time root bone animations with the current one.

I would like to change it to something like this, or better:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to increase grid density, open *N-panel* in *3D View*, reduce scale and increase line count:

[image]

Comment: It does still not look as clear as the above from my question. I try to make the lines white.

Comment: @Black you can change color of the grid floor lines only in the theme settings (User Prefs > Theme) for 3D viewport. Note that only color will be changed there, no different thickness lines etc. As another solution find a texture and assing it to a plane

Comment: ok but some of this will only work in ortographic view, I was looking for a possibilty to change the grid so that it is noticable in any view.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an addition to @Serge L answer.

You can change color of the **Grid** in **User Preferences** > **Themes** > **3D View** > **Grid**.

Also, and this can be seen in **Top Ortho** view, **Subdivision** value is responsible for those thicker white grid size.

[image: 1]

Comment: Changing subdivisions does not do anything for me.

Comment: @Black In Top Ortho view?

Comment: Nevermind, it works but I noticed that it was only visible when zooming in, because there were too many subdivisions on a too high scale